# Sharing lock-less resource between threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm porting my C++ chess engine in Rust. I have a big hash table shared between search threads and in the C++ version this table is lock-less; there is no mutex for sharing read/write access. Here is [the theory](http://www.craftychess.com/hyatt/hashing.html), if you are interested.

In the Rust version of this code, it is working fine, but uses a `Mutex`:

```
let shared_hash = Arc::new(Mutex::new(new_hash()));

for _ in 0..n_cpu {
    println!("start thread");
    let my_hash = shared_hash.clone();
    thread_pool.push(thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut my_hash = my_hash.lock().unwrap();
        let mut search_engine = SearchEngine::new();
        search_engine.search(&mut myhash);
    }));
}

for i in thread_pool {
    let _ = i.join();
}
```

How could I share the table between threads without a mutex?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an appropriate answer to this.  If a data structure doesn't require locking, then you won't need a mutex.  If it does, you *do* need a mutex, and trying to avoid using one is unsafe.  I don't know if there's an already-existing, applicable solution because you haven't indicated what you're trying to do other than "no mutex".  And if there isn't, then this devolves into "recommend a library" (which might be closed for being too broad), or "how do I write a lock-free data structure" (which is *also* probably too broad).

Comment: Also, flipping through that link (I don't have time to read an entire article to try and answer a somewhat vague question), I wonder why you can't just use `Cell<u64>`.  But I don't know what `new_hash()` does, so \*shrug\*

Comment: As Matthieu M. answers, you need to make your data structure implement `Sync`, which indicates it can be shared between threads safely. This changes the problem to your real question: "how do I write this **particular** lockless data structure in Rust?". To do that, you will *likely* need to write unsafe code. It seems the hashtable in question requires certain **hardware** preconditions (e.g. 64-bit stores to memory are naturally atomic) and **software** preconditions (e.g. you are storing two 64-bit values). That seems to indicate the datastructure is not portable.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, actually: the `Mutex` is unnecessary if the underlying structure is already `Sync`.

In your case, an array of structs of atomics for example would work. You can find Rust's available atomics [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/).

Answer (score 1):

[Data races are undefined behavior](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) in both C++ and Rust. Just Say No.

The right way is to build your table out of [atomic integers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html). It's rocket science. [You have to decide case by case](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.load) how much you [care about the order of memory operations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html). This does clutter up your code:

```
// non-atomic array access
table[h] = 0;

// atomic array access
table[h].store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
```

But it's worth it.

There's no telling what the performance penalty will be -- you just have to try it out.